# Select columns that endswith() and include main column R

Tags: r

I have a large data frame that I am trying to subset, now for this case I am sub-setting columns that ends with *_old* but now I want this subset to come with column *v1* which has rows of columns that ends with *_old*. Here is my data frame sample:

```
dput(df)
structure(list(v1 = c("c3", "c4", "c6"),
               v2_diff = c("Jacy","Jane", "Orange"),
               v3_old = c("Jack","Janet", "petere"),
               v4_new = c("Jack","Janet", "petere"),
               v4_old = c("Jack","Janet", "petere")),
          class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -3L))
```

here is what I tried but I only get columns that endswith *_old* without column *v*1. How can I add this

```
df_old <- df %>% select(ends_with("_old"))
```

Expected output

```
dput(df)
structure(list(v1 = c("c3", "c4", "c6"),
               v3_old = c("Jack","Janet", "petere"),
               v4_old = c("Jack","Janet", "petere")),
          class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,  -3L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
df_old <- df %>% select("v1",ends_with("_old"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `matches`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    select(matches("^v1|_old$"))
```